# Applet Loading Error - Jasper Report

Tags: java, applet, jasper-reports

I have encountered an error with my applet that I can not figure out solution. I am loading my java applet which encompass a simple jasper viewer in it. When the applet is loaded it throws following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet JasperReportServlet threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ReferenceMap
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.<init>(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.createDefaultRegistry(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:80)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.<clinit>(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:68)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:76)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:182)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:77)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:87)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:142)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:78)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:624)
    at com.dbhl.app.report.generator.JobUpdateGenerator.getJasperPrintObject(JobUpdateGenerator.java:279)
    at com.dbhl.app.report.JasperReportServlet.processJobUpdate(JasperReportServlet.java:153)
    at com.dbhl.app.report.JasperReportServlet.getJasperPrintObjectByLedgerType(JasperReportServlet.java:79)
    at com.dbhl.app.report.JasperReportServlet.service(JasperReportServlet.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Below is my applet configuration and I am loading applet using standard java deployment toolkit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=basePath%>js/deployJava.js">
</script>

<script>
  var user = '<%=request.getParameter("user")%>';

  var attributes = {
    code : 'applet.EmbeddedViewerApplet.class',
    archive : '<%=basePath%>resources/appletviewer.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/jasperreports-applet-4.0.0.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/jasperreports-4.0.0.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/commons-digester-1.7.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar,<%=basePath%>resources/org-netbeans-core.jar',
    width : "100%",
    height : 600
  };

  var parameters = {
    fontSize : 16,
    REPORT_URL : '<%=basePath%>servlet/JasperReportServlet?startDate=<%=request.getParameter("startDate")%>&endDate=<%=request.getParameter("endDate")%>&user=' + user + '&reportType=<%=request.getParameter("reportType")%>'
  };

  var version = '1.4';
  deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
</script>
```

All the jars I need in the applet exist in the resource folder of my webroot, which are

- appletviewer.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.7.jar
- commons-javaflow-20060411.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- jasperreports-4.0.0.jar
- jasperreports-applet-4.0.0.jar
- org-netbeans-core.jar

All the jars are signed today, so no validity expires. I have double checked everything, but it always shows the above error. In iReport I can view the report and it is compiled to jasper object with no error.

[The java console from control panel](http://pastebin.com/Xt6303tT)

I checked in the temp cache that the collections file is downloaded successfully and in the above console log it shows that the jars are successfully downloaded to the host computer.
**Why is the `ClassNotFoundException` happening?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from server side I came to know after tracing a console log, in my server classpath comons-collections is missing, I added it and things work perfectly.

Comment: what do you mean by "this does not provide an answer to the question".if you read the answer carefully you will kow the situation.